# How to define a shape and uniformly distribute points on it

Tags: c#, geometry, .net-core

My goal is to find a way to define a shape and uniformly distribute points on it on a 2D plane.

I was meaning to use `Geometry` set of classes in `System.Windows.Media`, along with some sort of SVG library to store the shape, but none of them have been ported to .Net Core yet.

Any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: An arbitrary shape? Calculate some simple bounding shape (e.g. a rectangle), sample the bounding shape, and reject points that lie outside of your target shape.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Not sure I understand, sorry. Say I have a collection of lines how would i uniformly place points on them.

Comment: Ah, only on the edges? Then just calculate the total length of the lines, sample a random number between 0 and the total length, and place the point this far away from an arbitrary start point.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Makes sense now. Thanks!